# In ApiWrapper.php line 187: Impossible to connect, please check your Algolia Application Id

Tags: php, laravel, e-commerce, algolia

hi i have followed ecommerce training with laravel and laravel voyager, i have downloaded a project in githup `https://github.com/drehimself/laravel-ecommerce-example`, i have execute `composer require laravel / scout` then `php artisan vendor: publish - -provider = "Laravel \ Scout \ ScoutServiceProvider"` while it works, I have created an account in `Algolia`, I have created an `index`, I have API keys `Application ID` = **** VH and `Admin API Key` = ******** ****************** b34, I put it in `.env`,

```
ALGOLIA_APP_ID=*** VH
ALGOLIA_SECRET=***************************b34
SCOUT_QUEUE = true
```

**scout.php**

```
'driver' => env('SCOUT_DRIVER', 'algolia'),
'prefix' => env('SCOUT_PREFIX', ''),
'queue' => env('SCOUT_QUEUE', true),
'algolia' => [
        'id' => env('ALGOLIA_APP_ID', ''),
        'secret' => env('ALGOLIA_SECRET', ''),
    ],
```

but when I run `php artisan scout: import "App \ Product"` or `php artisan db: seed` it tells me gives error.

```
In ApiWrapper.php line 187:
   Impossible to connect, please check your Algolia Application Id.
```

jai Download the last `cacert.pem`, and put `curl.cainfo = "D: \ wamp \ bin \ php \ php7.2.18 \ extras \ ssl \ cacert.pem"` in `php.ini`
the error always stays